# jquery ie8 $(selector).html(large data) can not display

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, dom

I'm using Jquery ajax to retrieve large data of about 3000~15000 lines of html(>280K). I wan't to

display this in ie8 but it doesn't work. However, if the data is smaller it will work.

```
//.....
$.ajax({type:'POST' ,url:'${ctx}course/${course.productid}.html',data:data,success: function(result, textStatus){
    //here it can display in chrome,ie10,11 and others. but it is can not work in ie8.
    //result has some javascript and html
    $('#content').html(result);
    }})
```

and i had try the $('#content').html(result.substr(100000)); then it can work~~

so ,who can help me!

Comment: Make sure the returned HTML is valid, IE8 doesn't like invalid markup.

Comment: @undefined hi,i try the $('#content').html(result.substr(100000)); and it can work~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 has problems inserting big amount of strings. I fix it using insertAfter or, simply, using innerHTML function.

Weird bug.

Answer (score 1):

try with  $(obj).html(result.d);

Comment: $('#content').html(result.d);

Comment: did you you alert result ? and getting result value?

Comment: @Dinesh there is about 280K data ,i debug it use network monitor,the data is right. and the question is done, if had fixed it use document....innerHtml